# php - Look for a PHP book that tells practical techniques

Tags: php

I am looking for a PHP book that introduces some real world practical techniques.

Does anyone know such a book?

Best wishes

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by `real world practical techniques`?  Are you just looking for a recipe book that you can copy and paste from?  Or are you looking for methodologies to solve real world problems?  Or something else entirely?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

PHP Cookbook
http://oreilly.com/catalog/9781565926813

The PHP Cookbook is a collection of problems, solutions, and practical examples for PHP programmers. The book contains a unique and extensive collection of best practices for everyday PHP programming dilemmas. It contains over 250 recipes, ranging from simple tasks to entire programs that demonstrate complex tasks, such as printing HTML tables and generating bar charts -- a treasure trove of useful code for PHP programmers, from novices to advanced practitioners.

Comment: Hi Fosco, Is the code for the recipes presented in this book still relevant or is it outdated considering the latest edition for this book was published in 2006 and it's 2012 now and the current php version is 5.4? How much has Php changed(improved fucntions/techniques) between then and now ?

Comment: @user481913 I suppose the general ideas are still solid, but certain syntax and methods have changed.   It's been a while since I've looked at it, so I would probably get a newer book.

Comment: Thanks Fosco for answering.  I don't see any newer book in the market that is as extensive and comparable to the php cookbook.

Comment: I want to read this to learn how to accomplish different things such as providing/reading rss feeds, file uploads, image resizing etc.  Just as you say, I guess most ideas/techniques to accomplish a task  would work the same way,although the function names might have changed to allow for the improved functionality/performance benefits or newer libraries. Do you think it is still relevant to use this book to understand the basics/ideas behind accomplishing something or is it better to learn a php framework straigt away and look at it's code for basic understanding to accomplish different tasks?

Comment: @user481913 Yes it's still relevant... grab it up and enjoy. :)  My advice would be to stay away from frameworks until you could technically do it all yourself (and therefore understand it.)

Answer (score 4):

[The PHP Anthology: 101 Essential Tips, Tricks & Hacks](http://www.sitepoint.com/books/phpant2/?historicredirect=phpant1)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[PHP Solutions: Dynamic Web Design Made Easy](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430232498)

You want to make your websites more dynamic by adding a feedback form, creating a private area where members can upload images that are automatically resized, or perhaps storing all your content in a database. The problem is, you're not a programmer and the thought of writing code sends a chill up your spine. Or maybe you've dabbled a bit in PHP and MySQL, but you can't get past baby steps. If this describes you, then you've just found the right book. PHP and the MySQL database are deservedly the most popular combination for creating dynamic websites. They're free, easy to use, and provided by many web hosting companies in their standard packages.

Answer (score 0):

PHP and MySQL Web Development (4th Edition)

[http://www.amazon.com/PHP-MySQL-Web-Development-4th/dp/0672329166](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0672329166)

I'd say this book is a good start especially if you want to create a shopping cart site.